# apache + php-fpm: Apache forwarding some png requests to php-fpm suddenly

Tags: apache, php

Recently set up PHP-FPM on a server with apache and it's working marvellously, however some png files I'm getting access denied for example https://socialsavanna.com/scripts/candy-1.6.0/res/img/action/statusmessage-off.png

In the error logs i'm getting

```
FastCGI: server "/{DirectoryToCGIBin}/php5-fcgi" stderr: Access to the script '/{DirectoryToWebsite}/scripts/candy-1.6.0/res/img/action/statusmessage-on.png' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)
```

Other pngs are working fine, why is Apache forwarding this to FastCGI to parse as a PHP file? any ideas how I stop this?

Thanks

Edit: Configuration

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.shtml index.cgi
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /{DirectoryToCGIBin}/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /{DirectoryToCGIBin}/php5-fcgi -socket /{socketPath}/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header    Authorization

    # For monitoring status with e.g. Munin
    <LocationMatch "/(ping|status)">
            SetHandler php5-fcgi-virt
            Action php5-fcgi-virt /php5-fcgi virtual
    </LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Why use Apache & PHP-FPM? Why not nginx & PHP-FPM? I'm fairly certain Apache comes with Apache

Comment: I'll be looking at Nginx later down the line, I'm more familiar with Apache so one step at a time but the site it running a LOT better just switching mod_php to php-fpm.

Comment: "Apache comes with Apache"?

Comment: @covener i'm fairly sure iWontStop was trying to point out their hatred for Apache.

Comment: Was just curious what it meant (or was supposed to say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obviously your LocationMatch which has "status" in the regex, which matches your filename statusmessage-on.png.

Without more details of what you had expected to match, it will be hard to suggest how to make that more specific.  If you meant the URL to start with either of those things, try

```
<LocationMatch "^/(ping|status)">
```